# php image from portrait to landscape

Tags: php, landscape, portrait

I'm using ImageResize php library in order to resize and crop images.

But now, I'm facing a problem that I've can't find a solution, and it is to convert and image from portrait to landscape.

Ofcourse I can do it deforming the image, but I want to achieve something like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBPUq.jpg)

So, the point is how to put the portrait image inside a landscape background in order to not deform it.

Any idea?

Cheers.

Comment: Post some link where one can find the library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Manually, you can resize in Plain PHP like this:

```
//define image path
$filename="image.jpg";

// Load the image
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

//and save it on your server...
file_put_contents("myNEWimage.jpg",$rotate);
```

I have an image class on Github (no rotate mind you), and it has a resize and crop. The logic in there basically keeps the aspect ratio correct and crops off overlapping stuff. You could do something similar after rotating:

https://github.com/delboy1978uk/image/blob/master/src/Image.php#L163-L180

```
public function resizeAndCrop($width,$height)
    {
        $target_ratio = $width / $height;
        $actual_ratio = $this->getWidth() / $this->getHeight();
        if($target_ratio == $actual_ratio){
            // Scale to size
            $this->resize($width,$height);
        } elseif($target_ratio > $actual_ratio) {
            // Resize to width, crop extra height
            $this->resizeToWidth($width);
            $this->crop($width,$height,true);
        } else {
            // Resize to height, crop additional width
            $this->resizeToHeight($height);
            $this->crop($width,$height,true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its like movies in widescreen. if you convert a landscape to portrait, if you want to keep the entire image, there will be black bars above and below. Similarly the other way around, a portrait to landscape will have black to the left and right.
However if you want to fill in the black spaces, you need to widen the portrait image to the width of your landscape, whilst maintaining the ratio. However this means that the top/bottom of the portrait image will be cut off. This is why widescreen advertises 'See what you're missing!'